# Rails where query for has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have workshops table and categories table.

Workshop model:

```
  has_many :workshop_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :workshop_categories
```

Category model:

```
  has_many :workshop_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :workshops, through: :workshop_categories
```

And I have a WorkshopCategory model:

```
class WorkshopCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :workshop
 belongs_to :category
end
```

I want to query active (active is a scope) workshops depending on categories. Tried this in workshop model:

```
  def self.browse(params)  
   workshops = Workshop.active.order( "created_at DESC" )
   workshops = workshops.joins(:categories).where(:categories => { :id => params[:category]}) if params[:category].present?
   workshops
  end
```

But I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
```

What is the proper way of this query? Everything that I can find on the internet is outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because both categories and workshops has a column `id`

You need to do something like:

`workshops.joins(:categories).where('category.id = ?', ...)`

Notice how it now specifies which `id` you're referring to.

Comment: Great, glad to hear!